# Cannot see debug symbols in Swift app extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, crash-reports, ios-app-extension

I created a custom keyboard in Swift, and made it crash intentionally inside my keyboard target. But I could not see any debug symbol in the crash report. I've set all "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO in Xcode 6.1.1 or 6.2 Beta 3. Here is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 59026289-7569-41BB-BFDC-E1186F854453
CrashReporter Key:   2ccc0eaebaa050c6b02f28b64d2e60e7dfe8ebe3
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             CrashIMEKeyboard [2564]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3F12CD05-15D4-4835-982B-A9104AA7B024/CrashIME.app/PlugIns/CrashIMEKeyboard.appex/CrashIMEKeyboard
Identifier:          com.superime.CrashIME.CrashIMEKeyboard
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-14 10:58:29.378 +0800
Launch Time:         2015-01-14 10:58:12.772 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000a02cc
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001000a02cc 0x100068000 + 230092
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001000a02c8 0x100068000 + 230088
2   CrashIMEKeyboard                0x00000001000498a4 0x100040000 + 39076
3   CrashIMEKeyboard                0x0000000100049c24 0x100040000 + 39972
4   UIKit                           0x0000000187be8d30 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
5   UIKit                           0x0000000187bd1e44 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 608
6   UIKit                           0x0000000187be86cc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187be8358 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 696
8   UIKit                           0x0000000187be18ac -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 680
9   UIKit                           0x0000000187bb4fa4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 260
10  UIKit                           0x0000000187e53f54 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14988
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187bb350c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1612
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ba9e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833b9c8c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833b7d3c __CFRunLoopRun + 708
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832e50a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
16  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c4875a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
17  UIKit                           0x0000000187c1a3bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
18  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001943b4268 _xpc_objc_main + 764
19  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001943b5f50 xpc_main + 196
20  Foundation                      0x00000001843bbc7c -[NSXPCListener resume] + 180
21  PlugInKit                       0x000000018e39690c -[PKService run] + 596
22  PlugInKit                       0x000000018e396544 +[PKService main] + 60
23  PlugInKit                       0x000000018e396934 +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 20
24  libextension.dylib              0x00000001933c4d88 NSExtensionMain + 64
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001941cea04 start + 0
```

Comment: I have similar problems with my app....searching hard for solutions....